# Updatable view with Postgresql and calculated fields

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, benchmarking, database-trigger

I have a view that calcul some fields. 
I wanted to update data from this view (model binding with a web framework). I had some troubles because calculated fields are not real columns. Then I've created a trigger function that handle this.

I did a benchmark of "update from event" and "update from event view". It appears that update triggered function is quite slower that the "normal" event update. Here is the benchmark result for 1000 creation/update of events:

```
# This report shows the user CPU time, system CPU time, the sum of the user and system CPU times, and the elapsed real time. The unit of time is seconds.
>> CREATE
              user     system      total        real
EVENT     3.268527   0.248713   3.517240 (  5.777483)
VIEW      3.423386   0.232107   3.655493 (  5.977695)
>> UPDATE
              user     system      total        real
EVENT     2.491350   0.227937   2.719287 (  4.586648)
VIEW      2.861838   0.199566   3.061404 (  6.240148)
=> nil
```

`CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE public.events (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    uuid uuid DEFAULT public.gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL,
    establishment_id bigint,
    name character varying NOT NULL,
    start_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    end_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    canceled boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL,
    published boolean DEFAULT false
);
```

`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`

```
# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) UPDATE events SET name='some name', updated_at='2020-05-07 10:05:07.769711' WHERE events.id = 16212


Update on events  (cost=0.29..8.38 rows=1 width=156) (actual time=0.187..0.194 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=17 dirtied=2
  ->  Index Scan using events_pkey on events  (cost=0.29..8.38 rows=1 width=156) (actual time=0.081..0.100 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (id = 16212)
        Buffers: shared hit=7 dirtied=2
Planning Time: 7.301 ms
Execution Time: 1.127 ms


# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) UPDATE invitations_event_view SET name='some name', updated_at='2020-05-07 10:05:07.769711' WHERE invitations_event_view.id = 16212


Update on invitations_event_view invitations_event_view_1  (cost=4.73..26.41 rows=1 width=1164) (actual time=1.800..1.810 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=15 dirtied=1
  ->  Subquery Scan on invitations_event_view  (cost=4.73..26.41 rows=1 width=1164) (actual time=0.418..0.455 rows=1 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=4 dirtied=1
        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=4.73..26.40 rows=1 width=369) (actual time=0.353..0.371 rows=1 loops=1)
              Group Key: e.id
              Buffers: shared hit=4 dirtied=1
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=4.73..26.21 rows=1 width=157) (actual time=0.251..0.307 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=4 dirtied=1
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=4.45..17.91 rows=1 width=161) (actual time=0.106..0.144 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Join Filter: (i.event_id = e.id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=4 dirtied=1
                          ->  Index Scan using events_pkey on events e  (cost=0.29..8.38 rows=1 width=141) (actual time=0.030..0.049 rows=1 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (id = 16212)
                                Buffers: shared hit=3 dirtied=1
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on invitations i  (cost=4.16..9.50 rows=2 width=28) (actual time=0.041..0.050 rows=0 loops=1)
                                Recheck Cond: (event_id = 16212)
                                Buffers: shared hit=1
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_invitations_on_event_id  (cost=0.00..4.16 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.021..0.030 rows=0 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (event_id = 16212)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=1
                    ->  Index Scan using guests_pkey on guests g  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.017..0.026 rows=0 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (i.guest_id = id)
Planning Time: 3.420 ms
Trigger invitations_event_view_on_update_trigger: time=1.254 calls=1
Execution Time: 2.425 ms
```

Here is the
Here is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION invitations_event_view_on_update() RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  UPDATE events
  SET establishment_id = NEW.establishment_id,
    name = NEW.name,
    start_at = NEW.start_at,
    end_at = NEW.end_at,
    canceled = NEW.canceled,
    updated_at = NEW.updated_at,
    published = NEW.published
  WHERE id = OLD.id;
  RETURN NEW;
END $$;
```

Here is the trigger creation

```
CREATE TRIGGER invitations_event_view_on_update_trigger
        INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON invitations_event_view
        FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION invitations_event_view_on_update();
```

My question is, how can I increase the performance of this function ?

I guess it's because I set all the fields instead of only the update onces but I'm not 100% sure. If experts can give a hint, it would be awesome.

**EDIT**

A try with `prepare`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION invitations_event_view_on_update() RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
  BEGIN
    PREPARE event_update(bigint, bigint, character varying, timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, integer, integer, boolean, timestamp without time zone, text, timestamp without time zone, boolean, integer) AS
      UPDATE events
      SET establishment_id = $2,
        name = $3,
        start_at = $4,
        end_at = $5,
        canceled = $6,
        updated_at = $7,
        published = $8
      WHERE id = $1;
    EXECUTE event_update(OLD.id, NEW.establishment_id, NEW.name, NEW.start_at, NEW.end_at, NEW.canceled, NEW.updated_at, NEW.published);
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE event_update;
    RETURN NEW;
  END
$$;
```

Comment: We'd need the `CREATE TABLE` statement for `events` and `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for your `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've added elements you asked. 

Comment: Thanks! Interesting would be the explain for the update on `invitations_event_view`.

Comment: I've added it. 

Comment: Hard to say. The query is complicated, but what sticks out is the high planning time. Do you have many tables or a high `default_statistics_target`?

Comment: Basically, the view is nothing more than events columns + calculated from `invitations` (left join + group by event id). Never heard about `default_statistics_target` then I don't think I'm using it differently from the default one.

Comment: Anyway, it only takes about 5ms. If you use prepared statements, you can cut down the time significantly.

Comment: Can I `prepare` on a `begin` of a function called by a trigger? I guess the `execute` won't work the same way as direct `update` isn't it?
I tried and I have `Views containing GROUP BY are not automatically updatable.`. Exactly what I have before creating the trigger.

Comment: The statement in the view will automatically have its plan cached. I am talking about the update of the view.

Comment: I think I get it but I need to `prepare` on the triggered function right? Unless `prepare` is nothing more than a function. `prepare`(`update events`...) + `execute` on a function returining `trigger` is not the same as `update events...` directly. The 1st one does not work.

Comment: `PREPARE stmt(text, timestamp, bigint) AS UPDATE invitations_event_view SET name=$1, updated_at=$2 WHERE invitations_event_view.id = $3`

Comment: Exactly. I did this. Then I use `execute stmt(...)` before `RETURN NEW`. I've added my try on the post. This is not working.

Comment: Don't do it in a function.

Comment: Basically, if I can just change the table where `create`/`update` is made, it would be enough. Can I do that?